# What's the fastest way to clone a big table in MonetDB?

Tags: monetdb

I got a table of 300 millions rows (and 10 columns) and I want to clone it in the same server.

So far I've tried with

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
CREATE TABLE cloned_table AS (SELECT * FROM big_table);
COMMIT;
```

but, after calling `COMMIT;` MonetDB starts creating a huge transaction log blocking all other queries.

This is the status during the operation

[Transaction size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoR8B.jpg)
[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IIEL.jpg)

As you can see the worst part is that MonetDB is using disk, even if there's a lot of free memory.

What would be the best approach??